# httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); this line is giving java.io.ioException what is the reason

Tags: java, android, http

I have this error:

```
java.io.ioException
```

when I execute this line

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

What is the reason....? Can anybody please help me?

I've been trying this for since yesterday and I am still failing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject object=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        object.addProperty("data", "123");// tis value u wil get frm web service it may change      
         envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet=true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(object);
         try {
             HttpTransportSE htp=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             htp.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
             SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String server_acknowledgement=resultString.toString();
            } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             exceptionArise=true;
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```